# What is the memory size when global ready only static string is been used to assign another string in constructor

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have two Classes in my example,"ABC" and "XYZ".

ABC is inherited from XYZ. In the Base class i have a string variable called _sql and its value is set at derived class

Say, I have two approaches to do as below.

I want to understand the memory size allocation and the better approach among these two and why?

**Approach1**: In Derived class "ABC" I am using a **static readonly string** and has constructed sql string query, then this static string value is assigned to base class string variable at the derived class constructor .

```
    class ABC:XYX
    {

          public static readonly string _sqlStatement = "Select * from table1 union" +
                                          "select * from table2 union" +
                                          "select * from table3" ;
          public ABC()
          {
              _sql =  _sqlStatement 

          }
    }
    class XYX
    {
       public string _sql;
    }
```

**Approach2**:. Same as above . But i am not using static readonly string variable instead I have assigned base class string variable with constructed sql string query at derived constructor.

```
    class ABC:XYX 
    { 
      public ABC()
      {
        _sql =  "Select * from table1 union" +
                                          "select * from table2 union" +
                                          "select * from table3";

      }
    }

    class XYX
    {
        public string _sql;
    }
```

I want to know better approach as well as the memory allocation between them.

Comment: A static variable is essentially a permanent memory leak, lives for the life of the program unless you explicitly set it back to null.  Which you can't do with a readonly variable.  Second snippet doesn't have this problem, it automatically gets garbage-collected.  There is no conceivable advantage of using a static here.

Comment: In this case what would be the size of the class?

Comment: It is the same size either way.  Static variables are stored in the loader heap, not the GC heap.